# Regex to match a number sequence like 1 2 3

Tags: c#, regex

I want to capture number sequences like **1 2 3** or **45 78 63**. I have been trying to create a regex that matches the sequence for a while.

I managed to write a regular expression pattern `(\b\d+\b\s){3,}`.

But the above pattern matches `1 2 3` and not `45 78 63`. Another problem with my pattern is that the captured group includes a trailing whitespace character.

Comment: `\d+\s\d+\s\d+` <- Does this work?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Actually it would match `1 2 3` but if the sequence is at the end of the line it would fail to capture the last number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d+\s\d+(\s\d+)+` seems simpler

You can test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1xn16Q/2).

Comment: If I use the string `1 2 3 and 42 45 46` it returns `1 2 3` , `42 45 4`

Comment: @AmatuerDev missed a plus

Comment: Well, I think I got what I needed. Thanks Yuriy

Comment: @AmatuerDev np.

Answer (score 1):

another variant would be

```
 (\s?(\d+)\s?){3}
```

here is a [RegEx_Com test](http://regexr.com/3eqjj)

to get rid of the trailing white space you can use the [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string res = Regex.Match(teststring, @"(\s?(\d+)\s?){3}").Value.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer a more complex example for those that don't need to match purely digits and don't want a long winded simple brute for solution.

The following regex:

```
^([01]?[0-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-2])[0-9]{7}$
```

Will match bank account routing numbers that must be **9 digits**, but has the following sequence acceptance requirements on the first 2 digits.

**00 through 12
or
21 through 32**

For example 004444444, 001234567 and 314444444 is good, but 204444444 is not